# Git - How do I stop files from being considered for merging?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

Our project has a development branch and many feature branches which we periodically merge into development branch. Sometimes when working on a feature branch I want to have access to classes from other branches (code in development branch) but I don't want merge the development branch into my feature branch.

Is there a way to fetch the dev branch into my feature branch without tracking it?

And hypothetically, if I accidentally merged dev branch into feature branch (I accidentally did), is there any way to exclude code from other branches from being considered for merge when merging the geature into dev?

Thank you

Comment: why not take the feature branch that you want to utilize and merge into your code base after you take an update of dev?

Comment: After I take an update of dev? What for? How? Right now I have dev merged into feature. What do you mean?

Comment: You say you want to utilize another members class from one of their feature branches?, why not merge there branch into yours?

Comment: Because I want my branch to be pure? What would I do if I wanted to merge my branch (with their code) into the dev branch and dev branch would contain a different commit than the one I merged into my branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to fetch the dev branch into my feature branch without tracking it?

It will help if you think about this problem from the point of view of the data model that Git uses to track changes.

If you haven't yet, have a look at [Git for Computer Scientists](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/), which illustrates the basics nicely.

Essentially, merges are commits with more than one parent. To get some content from one branch into another, you create a new commit which has content from both branches, with either two parents (merge) or one (regular commit; data was copied "manually").

> And hypothetically, if I accidentally merged dev branch into feature branch (I accidentally did), is there any way to exclude code from other branches from being considered for merge when merging the geature into dev?

It's possible to revert a merge (simply using `git revert SHA1-OF-MERGE-COMMIT`), but this will not help with conflict resolution for future merges, so it's better to avoid it in the first place.

There are newer version control systems based on a patch theory which do allow doing the things you're asking about (Darcs and Pijul), but that's not how Git works.

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for but it will do. Thank you.